# Applying PowerShell Desired State Configuration to Windows host from Linux control machine

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, dsc

I'm interested in using my Linux work machine to apply DSC configuration to Windows machines. I can find lots about using DSC to manage Linux, but that isn't what I'm interested in, I want to use it to manage Windows, but from on Linux. Ideally I'd like not to have to install too much extra on my Linux machine.

I'm aware of Ansible being able to apply DSC via the win_dsc module, but I am hoping for something more light-weight that doesn't require me setting up as much WinRM stuff or that duplicates as much functionality, more akin to just running `Start-DscConfiguration`, but that I can do on Linux (ideally without installing all of PowerShell, and without too much setup, which may be asking for the moon on a stick).

Comment: You can manage Windows machines from Linux using ansible.  And ansible can apply DSC configurations to Windows.

Comment: @Zoredache Yes, I'm hoping to find something that is more lightweight, that will just apply a DSC configuration to hosts, more like just running Start-DscConfiguration, but that I can run on Linux. I should have mentioned being aware of Ansible and win_dsc, but looking for a lighter-weight alternative.

Comment: It's very difficult to get lighter weight than ansible.